# How can I convert Wordpress Themes into Blogger Template

Tags: wordpress, blogger

I would like to know how I can convert my WP themes into the Blogger Template.

I've tried exporting XML and using http://wordpress2blogger.appspot.com to convert it. However, when I do this, I don't get my themes converted. I only import contents (posts, pages, etc) into my Blogger.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and found out that the Wordpress themes can't be converted automatically using wordpress2blogger.appspot.com or any other software products that I'm aware of. You just have to create a new template for the Blogger.